# Convert high-resolution images to low-resolution

Tags: java, image, compression

I am doing a web project on media manager. I upload high resolution images and need to convert these images to low resolution, so that the resulting image is compressed into a smaller size. How is this possible using Java?

Please post source code, if possible.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Image compression or image resize/resampling?

Comment: But the question is tagged "data-compression," so it's not crystal clear that it's dealing strictly with resampling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if I got it right, but if you want to change the size of an image, the Image class has a **getScaledInstance** method:

```
Image theImage = ...
Image scaled = theImage.getScaledInstance(32, -1, Image.SCALE_FAST);
```

For details see the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)) of Image

Comment: naveen may also need to read/write the image to a JPG or PNG.

Comment: which, BTW can be done with IamgeIO: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you  may be better off with Image.SMOOTH than Image.SCALE_FAST. Otherwise, good call.

Comment: it's just an example... same for the size of 32 pixel... kind of hard without knowing all details.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) used for this purpose.

Comment: JAI as Dan suggested is probably your best option if it is practical, JAI is not always available and depending on your deployment requirements/runtime constraints you may not be able to rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an parameter onto your image reader if you don't need to do anything with the high-res image, e.g.

```
ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
param.setSourceSubsampling(4, 4, 0, 0);
img = reader.read(0);
```

This will skip 3 out of 4 rows/column in the source data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a Linux server with the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) binaries installed, you could just do an `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` on `/usr/bin/convert`.  Just make sure you read/write to unique names (you can use `File.createTempFile()` to ensure that).